# NodeJS: Parsing data sequentially and asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequential

I am writing a NodeJS app that will load data from a database, parse it, and then save the parsed result to a different table in the database. Here is what I currently have:

```
parse(index, from, to) {
    var collection = this.getCollectionName();
    var interval = global.Settings.Parser.ParseInterval;

    var promises = [];
    console.log('%d - %d', from, from + interval);
    for(from; from < to; from += interval) {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var scoped = from;
            this.data.query(collection, {[index]: { $gte: from, $lte: from + interval}, (result) => {
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                    this.sendToBuilder(result[i]);

                resolve();
            });
        }));
    }

    promises.reduce((promise) => {
        Promise.resolve()
    });
}
```

The code seems to do what it should, but since the database query is asynchronous, it seems that out-of-order is a common occurrence. I do not want this to happen. I want each query and promise to execute sequentially to maintain the order of data.

I am trying the `array.reduce()` method to try and chain each promise to execute sequentially, but due to the nature of Promises it simply starts the promise and continues on, making them all fire simultaneously.

How can I ensure that it will execute sequentially? I don't mind delays between each promise as long as it doesn't block the actual thread.

Comment: `Promise.all(promises)` ...

Comment: Do you just want to know when all your db queries are done or do you want to actually run them in sequential order (waiting for one to finish before starting the next one)?

Comment: @jfriend00 Assuming `interval` is set to 1000, I'd like it to run the query, call `sendToBuilder()`, and then run the next one.

Comment: Well, the easiest way to do that would be to use `await` inside your loop, but I need to know what database you're using (to use a promise-based interface for it) and whether `this.sendToBuilder()` is async or not and if it is async, how you know when it's done.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am using MongoDB with the NodeJS connector. I have written a wrapper for it, called `DataClient`, which has a queue that stores queries and other operations while the database is being connected to. When the connection is finished the queue is executed.

Comment: What about the other part of my question?  Is `this.sendToBuilder()` async?  If so, how do you know when it's complete?

Comment: Plus, you `this.data.query()` doesn't seem to have any way to communicate back an error.

Comment: @jfriend00 `sendToBuilder()` is just a formatting function that allows for ES6 class polymorphism, where data from multiple sources can be parsed by an inheriting class top format the data into a general form. `this.data.query()` is a wrapper function that throws an error if there is one present.

Comment: How can it throw an error if it's asynchronous?  Sorry, but I can't provide you a good way to do what you're trying to do without understanding the async interfaces you're trying to use. This would be a heck of a lot easier if I could just use mogodb's promise interface directly.

Comment: @jfriend00 I can indeed use the MongoDB interface directly if you have a solution of doing it that way. I would just need to incorporate a way of ensuring it's already connected before executing anything, which would be easy to do with just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example in the spirit of your code using async/await:

```js
function getData(reqId, collection, index, gte, lte) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1;
        console.log(`[getData ${reqId}] delay: ${delay}`);

        const params = { collection, [index]: { $gte: gte, $lte: lte } };
        const results = [0, 1, 2].map(r => `result ${reqId}.${r}`);

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`[getData ${reqId}] this.data.query(${JSON.stringify(params)})`);
            resolve(results);
        }, delay);
    });
}

async function parse(index, from, to) {
    const collection = 'My Collection';
    const interval = 10;

    console.log(`Processing ${from} to ${to} by ${interval}:`);

    for (from; from <= to; from += interval) {
        const reqId = from;
        console.log(`[parse] BEGIN ${reqId}`);
        const results = await getData(reqId, collection, index, from, from + interval);
        results.forEach(result => {
            console.log(`[parse - awaited ${reqId}] this.sendToBuilder(${result})`);
        });
        console.log(`[parse] END ${reqId}`);
    }
}

parse('idx', 200, 250);
```

Comment: A promise is just a monitor for an async operation that has already been started.  If you already have an array of promises (which your code implies), then this isn't running the operations sequentially as they have all already been started.

Comment: lol oops - I answered too quickly this afternoon. I understand promises well and use this construct all the time (the correct for of with async/await and promise functions, not that one with them already invoked). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jfriend00 The code was updated to a working snippet. Do you see anything else missing?